# Apex Class Deployment: duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>

Tags: apex, deployment, class, duplicate-value

As many others have already done, I am providing yet another cautionary tale of the elusive, misleading, and downright frustrating, magical error:

```
duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>
```

The situation:

- Attempting to deploy an Apex Class from my local IDE
- Deployment fails, no error messages back whatsoever
- Created the empty Apex Class directly in the Salesforce Developer Console
- Pasted in content from local IDE
- Attempted to save, gets back the magical error message in the Problems list
- Searched online, everyone is saying one of the following:

  - It's version history on fields, turn it off, apparently this one is solved as of Winter '19 release
  - An update DML statement is violating some kind of uniqueness constraints.
- Commented out class body, no effect

  - So the issue isn't update DML statements either.
- Commented out superclass extend, no effect

I have posted the resolution I found below as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The Resolution!**

*It was a PEBKAC error.* But since this is an extremely vague error, I figure I will throw my own experience out. The more instances of this that get thrown out, I figure everyone will have a better grasp of how wide a range, and also how simple an issue can be and still set off this completely erroneous message.

That's the main focus here, is that even if my particular situation doesn't apply, *look for other things that are as stupidly simple as this.*

In my case, this class I was trying to deploy was borrowed from another. Created the new Apex Class, copy-pasted contents from another, gutted specific parts from the original and replaced them with specific parts for the new.

You can probably already guess where this is going.

*I forgot to change the name of the class at the top of the file.*

So, the class, the file being named **OpportunityHandler.cls**, had the declaration inside of **AccountHandler**. Problem is two fold: Not only does the file name not match the class declaration it holds inside, but this is now a second file trying to declare the class of **AccountHandler**.

The fix? Change the class declaration to match the file name.

After this it's pretty clear why it was a warning about duplicates. **It was a duplicate class declaration!** It still doesn't help that the error is so vague for such a simple, avoidable, PEBKAC-induced issue like this. But more than anything I just want to throw another example out of what this duplicate warning can mean.